# How to display live tweets in twitter-vibe using datasift in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am trying to configure an existing Ruby on Rails application (https://github.com/richcaudle/twitter-vibe) with datasift. Application displays live tweets of a user on the page. The datasift authentication parameters are set in config/social-config.yml. I have provided the correct authentication parameters in config/social-config.yml but yet the tweets do not show up. Only the html layout is displayed. Entire application is available in the same github link. I needed some help in fixing this application. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this app a while ago, before I joined DataSift. It's not something I've had time to maintain. I've added some instructions to the Readme file which I hope will help, I've also updated the app to use the latest DataSift library.

You'll need to have a Twitter, DataSift and Pusher account to get it running. Fortunately all are free or give you a free trial!

Probably all you were missing is that you need to start the data-collector & tasks scripts in /script to get it all running. I've added these to the Readme.

If you are going to use this in production or in public, please adapt the demo to meet Twitter's Terms of Service (for instance the display requirements). I created the app as an internal demo.

https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: Thank you very much for the instructions.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically run the script/data-controller.rb file instead of manually running it in command line each time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use the datasift ruby library. The repository that you mentioned; probably you might need a pusher account. You can use the datasift library.